# Favicon STILL not appearing in search engine results (since June 2023)

Tags: favicon

I've been having this problem for months now. After building my website on WIX, my favicon is STILL not appearing in search results, however it does within the tab in a browser. This is jeopardizing my business appearance. Wix support say everything looks goof on their end, so why isn't it updating on Google's end after months of waiting (almost 6 months). There must be something wrong somewhere for Google and all other search engines not to pick this up.

My website is : [www.jftreeservices.com](http://www.jftreeservices.com)

I cannot add the favicon with the name 'favicon.ico' to any directory manually, as you have to upload it via Wix's image page. The favicon is correctly sized. The site map is submitted and up to date. When analyzing things in Google Search Console, it always comes back with 'www.jftreeservices.com/favicon.ico' 404 errors. It's almost as if there is no redirect to my actual favicon file.

I have crawled the 'www.static.wixstatic.com...' where the image is located with Rich Results Test as this is not in my domain, and it says no items detected.

I have used this site 'https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.jftreeservices.com' and this does not show my favicon.

I feel like I have tried everything that is possible. I am fed up of waiting for things to just magically happen.

If anyone could look into this or view my source code/website, any help would be greatly appreciated as I am losing patience with this. Thank you so much.

I cannot add the favicon with the name 'favicon.ico' to any directory manually, as you have to upload it via Wix's image page. The favicon is correctly sized. The site map is submitted and up to date. When analyzing things in Google Search Console, it always comes back with 'www.jftreeservices.com/favicon.ico' 404 errors. It's almost as if there is no redirect to my actual favicon file.

I have crawled the 'www.static.wixstatic.com...' where the image is located with Rich Results Test as this is not in my domain, and it says no items detected.

I am expecting my favicon image to appear in search engine results.